# Dividing and Subtracting Items within a Single List

Tags: python, list, division, subtraction

Is there a way to subtract and/or divide all items together from a single list?

i.e. subtraction:

```
[200,10,50,40] --> 100
```

i.e. division:

```
[200,10,2] --> 10
```

I've been able to use sum() and math.prod() for addition and multiplication but I can't seem to find anything similar for subtraction/division

Comment: `functools.reduce` can do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
import functools
lis1=[200,10,50,40]
lis2=[200,10,2]
# For subtraction
print(functools.reduce(lambda a, b: a-b,lis1)) #100

#For division
print(functools.reduce(lambda a,b: a//b,lis2)) #10
```

**Brief explanation.**

```
first the two elements from the list are picked and perform the operation which provided in the lambda function. 
at second step previously obtained result and the third value of the list are picked and perform operation
at 3rd step previously obtained result and the 4th value of the list..
and so on till it pick the last element from the list
```

**Dry run: for subtraction**

```
pick first 2 elements 200 10 -> obtained result 190
pick previous obtained + third element 190 50 -> obtained result 140
pick previous obtained + fourth element 140 40 -> obtained result 100

lastly obtained result.
```